# To include css in odoo 9.0

Tags: css, odoo-9

I have problem including css in odoo9. Can you suggest any solution?

```
<template id="mystyle" name="My style" inherit_id="website.assets_backend">
    <xpath expr="link[last()]" position="after">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme_tutorial/static/less/style.less" type="text/less"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

```
.services{
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Hope this will help - http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/adding-static-resources-css-and-javascript-to-odoo/

Comment: Code examples were malformed to the point of not being shown.  Updated to make them visible and human readable.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the link of your css file on the template of backend assets there is two type of including css :

1- backend css  : use `web.assets_backend`

```
<template id="assets_backend" name="custom bar assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/your_module_name/static/src/css/your_css_file"/>               
    </template>
```

2. for qweb report css : use  : `report.assets_common`

   ```
   <template id="report_assets_backend" name="tip assets" inherit_id="report.assets_common">
       <xpath expr="." position="inside">
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="/your_module_name/static/src/css/you_css_file"/>
       </xpath>
   </template>
   ```